# Return all a tags in a parent div

Tags: javascript

I am trying to run some javascript (via Google tag manager) which will scrape my page and return all the tags which are in a specific parent div. the example I have is as follow:

```
<div class="class1">

<div class="subclass1">
<a href="url1">location1</a>
</div>

<div class="subclass2">
<a href="url2">location2</a>
</div>

<div class="subclass3">
<a href="url3">location3</a>
</div>

</div>
```

I would like to know the Javascript to return a string of all the tag urls 
in the following format `[url1,url2,url3]`

Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can select all the target anchor elements using `querySelectoAll` and the use `.map()` extract their `href` value to a array.

```js
var tags = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.class1 a[href]')).map((el) => el.getAttribute('href'));
snippet.log('tags: ' + tags);

//for older browser support
var tags = [].map.call(document.querySelectorAll('.class1 a[href]'), function(el) {
  return el.getAttribute('href')
});
snippet.log('tags 2: ' + tags);
```

```html
<!-- Provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
<div class="class1">

  <div class="subclass1">
    <a href="url1">location1</a>
  </div>

  <div class="subclass2">
    <a href="url2">location2</a>
  </div>

  <div class="subclass3">
    <a href="url3">location3</a>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Arun, exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: i have one issue that the string put a space in after the 77th character in the array any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Javascript code

```
function callMe(){
 var tags = [];
var count = $(".class1").children().length;
for(var i=0; i<count; i++){
     tags.push($('.class1').children().eq(i).find('a').attr('href'));    
}
console.log(tags);
}
```

You can see the live working code on [Plunker Here](https://plnkr.co/edit/qmdGlTiIM7H8WCstJ0jv?p=preview)

Comment: By the way `jQuery` is not tagged!

Comment: i have one issue that the string put a space in after the 77th character in the array any ideas?

Comment: No, it should not behave like this.  Maybe there is problem in your url string. Check it by other strings.